# AFRAME text-geometry component rotation from center?

Tags: text, rotation, aframe

Is there a way to setup the pivot point to be in the center? I am using text-geometry component and it rotates from a corner. i would like to make the text spin from the center.

```
<a-entity animation="property: rotation; dur: 5000;to: 0 360 0;loop:true;easing:linear" position="0 4 -3" scale="0.6 1.2 1" text-geometry="value: MultiMedia; font: #dawningFont; bevelEnabled: true; bevelSize: 0.1; bevelThickness: 0.1; curveSegments: 1; size: 1.5; height: 0.5;" material="color:yellow; metalness:0.9; roughness: 0.05; sphericalEnvMap: #chrome;"></a-entity>
```

I have tried adding a parent entity and adding the animation to the parent but it doesn't seem to fix it, instead it starts rotating in a circle path.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the `text-geometry` component doesn't have an `offset`ish property (source [here](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/blob/master/components/text-geometry/dist/aframe-text-geometry-component.js))

I'd tackle it like this: Once the text mesh is loaded - grab it and manually provide an offset.

1) You can grab the mesh quite easily:

```
let mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
```

2) To calculate the offset - get the width from the bounding box.

```
let bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.el.object3D);
let offset = (bbox.min.x - bbox.max.x) / 2 
mesh.position.set(offset, 0, 0)
```

You can check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vx1yafn3).

---

Now i have one major issue - maybe i don't know something - but there is no event emitted once the text mesh is loaded. I tried `loaded` or `window/document.onload` but they seem to execute just before the text mesh is being really loaded. I need it to load, otherwise the bounding box is infinite - making the offset calculation pretty much useless. In my fiddle i threw the code into a `setTimeout()`.

---

**Edit**

1) Its good idea to wait with the animation, until the above calculations are set. You can define a `startEvent` and emit it after repositioning the mesh

```
...
mesh.position.set()
this.el.emit("go")
```

..

```
<a-entity animation="startEvents: go"></a-entity>
```

2) you need to include the scale when calculating width. This is because the local space size is now different:

```
let xscale = this.el.getAttribute('scale').x
let offset = ((bbox.min.x - bbox.max.x) / xscale ) / 2 
mesh.position.set(offset, 0, 0)
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fux7jg0c/2/).

Comment: If you want me to elaborate on the bounding box, or anything else, feel free to ask

Comment: thanks, it worked, however, i'm trying to figure out how to compensate for the scale, which seems to modify the bbox and makes the offset.. offset if that makes any sense. I wonder if it would work if i apply the same scale to the bbox? i'm not familiar with THREEjs so i have to do some research on how to apply that?

Comment: @user1986245 i think i've figured it out, check out my update