# Center mesh position for text-geometry

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm struggling with the positioning of some [aframe text geometry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-text-geometry-component) and am wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way

I'm finding that when the box renders, the center point is at the minimum point of all the axises (bottom-left-close). This means the text expands more to the top-right-far than I would expect. This is different from aframe geometry entitites where the center point is at the very center of all axises.

Sorry if the above phrasing is confusing, I'm still not sure how to best describe things in a 3d space

What I'm thinking I need to do is calculate the bounding box after the element has loaded and change the position to the center. I've based that approach on the answer here [AFRAME text-geometry component rotation from center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892378/aframe-text-geometry-component-rotation-from-center).

Does that seem like the right direction? If so, I'm currently trying to do this through an aframe component

```js
aframe.registerComponent('center-all', {
  update() {
    // Need to wait for the element to be loaded
    setTimeout(() => {
      const mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
      const bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.el.object3D);
      const offsetX = (bbox.min.x - bbox.max.x) / 2;
      const offsetY = (bbox.min.y - bbox.max.y) / 2;
      const offsetZ = (bbox.min.z - bbox.max.z) / 2;
      mesh.position.set(offsetX, offsetY, offsetZ);
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

[This code](https://chief-dart.glitch.me) illustrates the problem I'm seeing
[image: Center at min axises]

[This code](https://picayune-polyester.glitch.me/) shows my attempted solution
[image: reposition incorrect attempt]

[This code](https://scratched-marlin.glitch.me/) (with the translation hard coded) is more like what I would like
[image]

Comment: Is it acceptable in your case to call `mesh.geometry.center()` to center mesh's geometry?

Comment: @prisoner849 Yeah, that seems to work well!  If you want to submit an answer with this, I'll gladly accept it. I also put together this which shows the fix https://tasty-menu.glitch.me/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextGeometry` and `TextBufferGeometry` are both subclasses of the respective geometry classes, and so both have the `boundingBox` property. You just need to compute it, then get its center point:

```
textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
const center = textGeo.boundingBox.getCenter(new Vector3());
```

Then `center` will accurately reflect the center of the geometry, in local space. If you need it in global space, you will need to apply the matrix of the mesh that contains `textGeo` to the `center` vector, e.g.

```
textMesh.updateMatrixWorld();
center.applyMatrix4(textMesh.matrixWorld);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure I understand  I've added my current code to hopefully illustrate my thinking.

This helps me calculate the center, but it still seems off center from where I expect it to be. I'll try to add a better code example tomorrow to show where I'm confused 

Comment: Ah, are you not actually trying to move the geometry but only move its origin (the point at which transformations are based)? If so, change the last line to `mesh.geometry.translate(offsetX, offsetY, offsetZ);`

Comment: My impression is that using `mesh.position.set` and `mesh.geometry.translate` have similar effects, though perhaps there are differences between them I don't understand  If that's correct, then I think I'm just unsure of how to calculate the offsets. What I show above doesn't seem to give the right results

Comment: To center:
`txtMesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox()`
`txtMesh.geometry.translate(-txtMesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.x/2,0,0)` (or create a parent group)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I add text to a scene and center it.

const fontLoader = new FontLoader();

fontLoader.load(
"/fonts/droid/droid_sans_bold.typeface.json",
function (font) {
const geometry = new TextGeometry("Hello World", {
font: font,
size: 4,
height: 4,
});

```
  const mesh = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
  const text = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mesh);

   // options if necessary to rotate text
  //text.position.set(0, 0.5, 11.5);
  //text.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

  geometry.computeBoundingBox();

  if (geometry.boundingBox) {
    geometry.translate(-geometry.boundingBox.max.x / 2, 0, 0);
  }

  scene.add(text);
}
```

);